# Execute custom script after page loaded with Ratchet\Push.js

Tags: javascript, ratchet-2, ratchet-bootstrap, push.js

So on the GitHub documentation for [Ratchet 2.0.2](https://github.com/twbs/ratchet) I found the following statement.

> Script tags containing JavaScript will not be executed on pages that
>   are loaded with push.js. If you would like to attach event handlers to
>   elements on other pages, document-level event delegation is a common
>   solution.

Can someone please spell out exactly how to get a custom `<script>` to execute after being loaded by `Push.js`?

On my first page, I have a Table view, with several links to other pages, one of them being a link to a second page with a Twitter Feed widget on it.

```
<li class="table-view-cell media">
    <a class="navigate-right" href="Twitter.php" data-transition="slide-in">
        <span class="media-object pull-left icon icon-person"></span>
        <div class="media-body">
            Twitter Feed
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

The second page only contains the twitter feed widget code. When I browse to this page directly (without being loaded by `Push.js`) everything loads correctly, but when it is loaded via Push.js, the script is not executed.

Can someone please explain what I need to do to get this script to execute after being loaded by `Push.js`? I've searched Google, Stack Exchange, and Github\Ratchet issues and have not been able to find a good example of how to accomplish this.

One solution would be to add `data-ignore="push"` to the link, but I want to know how to do with WITH `push.js`.

```
<div class="content">
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/XXXX" data-widget-id="XXXX">Tweets by XXX</a>
</div>
<script>
    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** below was how I originally solved this problem, which worked fine, but I came up with a better solution, which I posted as the answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207741/executing-several-js-files-with-ratchet-push-js-library/23316965#23316965)

---

I finally figured it out.

On your **first page**, you need to do the following...

```
var checkPage = function(){
    //Only run if twitter-widget exists on page
    if(document.getElementById('twitter-widget')) {
        loadTwitterFeed(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
    }
};

window.addEventListener('push', checkPage);
```

`checkPage()` will execute for every time a new page is loaded via push.

Answer (score 1):

Just made a change for Ratchet.js to make individual js works for each page more elegant.(https://github.com/mazong1123/ratchet-pro)

By using the new ratchetPro.js, we can do followings:

```
(function () {
    var rachetPageManager = new window.RATCHET.Class.PageManager();
    rachetPageManager.ready(function () {
       // Put your logic here.
    });
})();
```