# How does Ratchet and Phonegap work together

Tags: cordova, ratchet-2

From my understanding, Ratchet requires a server to change the contents of the view without actually changing the page itself. Does that mean any currently running JS files remain after the view change or not? Also, when used with Phonegap, is the page server still necessary or is that only for development with browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the currently running JS files remain after the view change. Like you said, you are not actually changing the page itself.

One thing to keep in mind is JavaScript on the requested page will NOT run. One method of loading JavaScript from the requested page is to use the method discuss in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207741/executing-several-js-files-with-ratchet-push-js-library/23316965#23316965).

Also, I'm not sure if this old issue still exists, but one gentleman had trouble getting PhoneGap and Ratchet to play nicely and was able to fix it by using the method discussed in the Ratchet Google Group Thread [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/goratchet/G8fXCAL91G4/4sRqJstip48J).

Comment: "Also, when used with Phonegap, is the page server still necessary or is that only for development with browsers?" What about that?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/RouR/vs-cordova-ng-ratchet it used both Apache Cordova and Ratchet

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not solution on your problem but it solved my problem with scrolling on old Android devices.

```
body
{
height: auto !important;
position: static !important; 
}
.content
{
height: 100% !important;
position: static !important;
}
```

Source: https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/issues/515#issuecomment-60918860